# how to solve java.net.SocketException: Connection reset when writing data to influxdb from spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, influxdb

Hi I built a spring boot application, and want to log heartbeats and metrics through influxdb. but recently when I ran this project again, I got error saying:
[image]

I was think this might be influxdb problem, I uninstalled and installed again
brew install influxdb. and run it, create table....
but still same error.

Any idea what happened?

it seems influx db didn't allow post?
I tried to use brower to visite localhost:8080/write?db=db_name&....
I got "Method not allow"

Comment: You probably sent a request it didn't understand so it closed the connection without even reading all of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, I tried use **influxd** to start influxdb, not

```
influxd -config /usr/local/etc/influxdb.conf
```

or

```
brew services restart influxdb
```

then it works!